# Array sorting even and odd accepting n values, with functions

Tags: c++

i am practicing C++ as a beginner and i cant seem to get this program to work, the aim is to display even and odd numbers after accepting the values from the user.. and it has counter to display the amount of even and odd values in the end.

but it just displays the Even values on both the even and odd arrays.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void EvenOdd(int num[], int even[], int odd[], int n, int& EC, int& OC)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "Enter the Numbers: ";
        cin >> num[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (num[i] % 2 == 0) {
            even[EC] = num[i];
            EC++;
        }
        else {
            odd[OC] = num[i];
            OC++;
        }
    }
}

void Display(int num[], int even[], int odd[], int n, int& EC, int& OC)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < EC; i++) {
        cout << "Even: " << even[i] << "\n";
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < OC; j++) {
        cout << "Odd: " << odd[j] << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n, EC = 0, OC = 0;
    int num[n], even[EC], odd[OC];
    cout << "How many numbers: ";
    cin >> n;

    EvenOdd(num, even, odd, n, EC, OC);
    Display(num, even, odd, n, EC, OC);

    cout << "Total number of Evens: " << EC << "\n";
    cout << "Total number of Odds: " << OC;
}
```

this is how the array is sorted
[image: 1]

Comment: `int num[n],even[EC],odd[OC];` are variable-length arrays and not allowed in standard C++. `n` is uninitialized. You can't first use `n` and then initialize it. Arrays don't grow.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  It should be screaming at you about `even[EC],odd[OC]` being zero sized arrays

Comment: [`-fsanitize=address`](https://godbolt.org/z/8fsfxG) (look at the bottom of the right window) - Before you fix that, there's no point in analyzing the result you get.

Comment: @NathanOliver they don't, because using non-const variable there make them VLAs.

Comment: @NathanOliver im using CodeBlocks

Comment: @SergeyA 2 problems (1) VLAs are not in the Standard and (2) the array sizes are set to `0` on the line above; which makes accessing any element of arrays UBs

Comment: You should replace the arrays with `std::vector`s

Comment: @ThomasSablik i initialized it.. and its still the same

Comment: Because it's not the only problem in your code. The arrays `even` and `odd` can hold 0 items. Arrays don't grow. You need `std::vector`, dynamic memory allocation or arrays that can hold enough items.

Comment: @RichardCritten never said anything to the contrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int num[n],even[EC],odd[OC];` are variable-length arrays and not allowed in standard C++. `n` is uninitialized. You can't first use `n` and then initialize it. The arrays `even` and `odd` can hold 0 items. Arrays don't grow.

You need `std::vector`, dynamic memory allocation or arrays that can hold enough items.

Here is a solution using `std::vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void EvenOdd(std::size_t n, std::vector<int> &even, std::vector<int> &odd) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Enter the Numbers: ";
        int el;
        std::cin >> el;
        if (el % 2 == 0) {
            even.push_back(el);
        } else {
            odd.push_back(el);
        }
    }
}

void Display(const std::vector<int> &even, const std::vector<int> &odd) {
    for (const auto el : even) {
        std::cout << "Even: " << el << '\n';
    }

    for (const auto el : odd) {
        std::cout << "Odd: " << el << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    std::size_t n;
    std::cout << "How many numbers: ";
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<int> even, odd;

    EvenOdd(n, even, odd);
    Display(even, odd);

    std::cout << "Total number of Evens: " << even.size() << '\n';
    std::cout << "Total number of Odds: " << odd.size();
}
```

You should enable pedantic compiler warnings and read them. That are the warnings I get from your code:

```
prog.cc: In function 'void Display(int*, int*, int*, int, int&, int&)':
prog.cc:24:18: warning: unused parameter 'num' [-Wunused-parameter]
   24 | void Display(int num[], int even[], int odd[], int n, int& EC, int& OC)
      |              ~~~~^~~~~
prog.cc:24:52: warning: unused parameter 'n' [-Wunused-parameter]
   24 | void Display(int num[], int even[], int odd[], int n, int& EC, int& OC)
      |                                                ~~~~^
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:38:9: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'num' [-Wvla]
   38 |     int num[n], even[EC], odd[OC];
      |         ^~~
prog.cc:38:17: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'even' [-Wvla]
   38 |     int num[n], even[EC], odd[OC];
      |                 ^~~~
prog.cc:38:27: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'odd' [-Wvla]
   38 |     int num[n], even[EC], odd[OC];
      |                           ^~~
prog.cc:38:14: warning: 'n' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
   38 |     int num[n], even[EC], odd[OC];
      |
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/G8lwiENRtDMh6fHa

Comment: I started writing [an answer](https://godbolt.org/z/GcP63f) but your's is too similar. One thing: I'd skip the `num` vector and populate `odd` and `even` directly.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, that makes sense. I'll fix it.